# how to extract only date number from a date column which is in format Mmm-dd in padas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe (sample of which is shown below):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'Date': ['Jan-1', 'Jan-1', 'Jan-4', 'Jan-4', 'Jan-5', 'Jan-6', 'Jan-6', 'Jan-6']})
```

i.e. :

```
  Date
0 Jan-1
1 Jan-1
2 Jan-4
3 Jan-4
4 Jan-5
5 Jan-6
6 Jan-6
7 Jan-6
```

I want to extract only the day part from it. which should return me as follows:

```
1
1
4
4
5
6
6
6
```

and what I am trying is as follows:

```
df['Date2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format="%M-%d")
```

but this has resulted in error... not sure what I am doing wrong here.
how to extract the `day` then, in my case?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to extract the year, month and day in Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41138190/how-to-extract-the-year-month-and-day-in-pandas)

Comment: No, Rakesh. Date format is different. and issue is more related to correct date format in Pandas on which the rest action can be performed. Thanks, anyways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First use `%b` for match name of month and then [`Series.dt.day`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.day.html):

```
df['Date2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format="%b-%d").dt.day
```

Or if possible extract numbers and convert to integers:

```
df['Date2'] = df['Date'].str.extract('(\d+)').astype(int)
```

---

```
print (df)
    Date  Date2
0  Jan-1      1
1  Jan-1      1
2  Jan-4      4
3  Jan-4      4
4  Jan-5      5
5  Jan-6      6
6  Jan-6      6
7  Jan-6      6
```

Comment: wow. i never knew that this simple looking problem would be this much difficult.